# cli/c++ using MAC address in raw socket

Tags: c++-cli

I want to use MAC address instead of IP address in RAW socket. 
Is it possible?

Note: CLI/C++ and the system is connected to two devices

Comment: I need to define destination address using MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

So sorry